# Entity Framework: table1_table2id mapping to table2_id

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Lets say I have two tables like this:
person: id, first_name, last_name, phone_id

phone: id, phone_number

person.phone_id is always equal to a phone.id. Instead of my entity showing person.phone_id, I'd like it to show person.phone_number. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called "[Entity Splitting](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-entity-splitting/)." It's a moderately advanced technique, but it's possible.

Note that you should already have a `person.phone.phone_number`.